# Problems with npm auth-net-cim

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, node-expat

[image]

I can't figure out where this reference to node-expat 1.6.1 is coming from. I've looked into each module's repo and their dev dependencies and they all reference node-expat 2.0.0.

No idea whats going on, just switched to a windows 8 pc and i can't get my project up and running.

Here's my dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "hbs": "2.4.x",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "passport": "0.1.x",
    "passport-local": "0.1.x",
    "passport-facebook": "1.0.x",
    "passport-twitter": "1.0.x",
    "passport-google-oauth": "0.1.x",
    "passport-http": "0.2.x",
    "passport-http-bearer": "0.2.x",
    "passport-oauth2-client-password": "0.1.x",
    "mongodb": "1.4.x",
    "mongoose": "3.8.x",
    "mongoosastic": "0.2.x",
    "mongoose-text-search" : "0.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "0.7.x",
    "mongoose-validator": "0.2.x",
    "connect-redis": "1.4.x",
    "connect-mongo" : "0.3.x",
    "connect-flash" : "0.1.x",
    "aws-sdk": "2.0.x",
    "gm": "1.14.x",
    "async": "0.2.x",
    "underscore": "1.6.x",
    "nodemailer": "0.6.x",
    "express-useragent": "0.0.x",
    "auth-net-cim": "git://github.com/digitaljohn/authorize-net-cim.git#master",
    "hashids": "0.3.3",
    "numeral": "1.5.x",
    "string": "1.8.x",
    "aws-snsclient": "0.2.0",
    "campaign": "1.2.1",
    "oauth2orize": "1.0.1",
    "formidable": "1.0.14",
    "archiver": "0.9.0",
    "ffmetadata": "1.0.2"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-devtools": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "*",
    "grunt-concurrent": "*",
    "grunt-nodemon": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-rename": "*",
    "grunt-s3-sync": "*",
    "grunt-modulus-deploy": "*",
    "uglify-js": "~2.2.5",
    "gulp-util": "~2.2.14",
    "gulp": "~3.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the content of package.json?

Comment: updated my original post, though i m not sure how that would help. The project used to work just fine, no problems at all (on my mac) but i switched to a windows machine just a couple of days ago. Appparently some modules need to be compiled with c and xml2json (a dependency of auth-net-cim) needs exactly that node-expant in particular.

Comment: If you need a dev environment, install Visual Studio 2013 community edition, and the latest Python 2.7, both are needed for node compiled modules.